# excel formula if average is greater than or equal to 85 then count scores lower than 80

Tags: excel, formula

Given the data inside the table, how to count scores that are less than 80, only to those who have an average score of 85 and above

```
score
```

```
joy 75  82  77  76  75  75  77  82  82  85  75  80  75  AVERAGE is 77
jay 85  93  92  95  90  80  86  88  91  82  84  94  87  AVERAGE is 89
jan 75  77  76  75  78  75  75  75  75  78  80  80  75  AVERAGE is 76
jen 88  95  88  92  89  85  89  97  94  92  89  95  91  AVERAGE is 91
```

[image: sample]

Comment: can somebody help me please?

Comment: thanks.. Given the data inside the table, how to count scores that are less than 80, only to those who have an average score of 85 and above

Comment: @ChylianBesanes Please try my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula

```
=IF(O2>=85,COUNTIF(B2:N2,"<80"),"")
```

You can also calculate count with calculating average in a separate column. Try-

```
=IF(AVERAGE(B2:N2)>=85,COUNTIF(B2:N2,"<80"),"")
```

[image]